# ionic $state.go() Won't change state, No Error in Inspect Elements

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

For some reason ui router won't change state or does change it but it does not render it, 
here is my code

```
    angular.module('splash', ['ionic'])

    .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
          // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
          StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
      });
    })


    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider

        .state('splash', {
        url: '/splash',

        templateUrl: '/splash.html',
      })

      .state('splash.login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: "SplashCtrl"
          }
        }
      })

      .state('splash.register', {
          url: '/register',
          views: {
            'menuContent': {
              templateUrl: 'register.html',
              controller: "SplashCtrl"
            }
          }
        })
      // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/splash');
    }])

    .controller('SplashCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.go = function(state) {
            $state.go(state);
        }

    });
```

is there anything wrong with what I am doing? in the html file I only add the ng-app directive, it loads the first state without any problems but it does not change states
kindly help me in this regard if you have any idea
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where are you calling the $scope.go function?

Comment: on buttons in another html page as ng-click="go('stateName')"

Comment: why not just use [`ui-sref`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#ui-sref)?

Comment: Also Not Working, there are no errors but the state is not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your code and added some comments. Feel free to ask about any uncentainties.

```
        angular.module('splash', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})


.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('splash', {
    url: '/splash',
    abstract : true, // Because your are have child-states under de 'splash' state, you should set it abstract : true;
    templateUrl: '/splash.html',
  })

  .state('splash.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
      'menuContent': { // Is only your  menu contect visible on your app ?
        templateUrl: 'login.html',
        controller: "SplashCtrl"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('splash.register', {
      url: '/register',
      views: {
        'menuContent': {
          templateUrl: 'register.html',
          controller: "SplashCtrl"
        }
      }
    })

  // Using stateParams your are able to pass values when switching states.
  .state("splash.third", {
    url : "/thirdpage/:text", // This value is referencing the passed value in the 3th button. 
    views : {
      "menuContent" : {
        templateUrl : "thirdpage.html",
        controller : "SplashCtrl"
      }
    }
  }); // You forgot a ;

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/splash');
}])

.controller('SplashCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  // Your controller shouldn't know anything about routing. UI-router is fixing that your you! =]
  // An controller is supposed to act as glue between your data (services/factories) and your scope (html templates/directives)
  // e.g.

  $scope.buttonText = "Third button";
});


// On your splash.html

<button ui-sref="splash.login">Login</button>
<button ui-sref="splash.register">Register</button>
<button ui-sref="splash.third({ text : buttonText })">{{buttonText}}</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, making the state "splash" abstract results in blank page, what I have is 3 pages in the www directory and I want to route between them, it is not working with my code and also not working with yours I am notsure what is the problem

Comment: thank you with your comment I was able to understand where the problem was, I was referring to the wrong view

Comment: Glad I could help!